Nginx + Passenger for Rails app getting error No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader
I am deploying my Rails app to DigitalOcean using Capistrano. On my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 24.04, I installed Nginx & Passenger. I could deploy to server using cap production deploy, however, when accessing the url, I get this error
App 38095 output: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/bin/ruby: 
App 38095 output: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current
App 38095 output:  (
App 38095 output: LoadError
App 38095 output: )
App 38095 output: 
[ E 2024-10-29 10:45:44.4288 37874/Ti age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current: The application process exited prematurely.
  Error ID: c6f3b06c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-73w0A5.html

However, the app path is correctly
The Passenger also running when I run passenter-status
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current (production):
  App root: /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current
  Requests in queue: 0

Below is my passenger setting
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;

And my site-enabled config
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  #passenger_preload_bundler on;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name padel-booking_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}


the site.config root -- /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current/public <>  /home/ubuntu/padel-booking/current/ -- also, adding your deployment configuration would be useful
